# Android Studio Libgdx Time Passed

Tags: android, time, libgdx

I have a problem in my app. I want to turn off immunity time after 10 seconds, so I measure the time passed like this: I have a startTime variable on create method and it gets value System.currentTimeMillis(). After this I check on render function that System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 10000. This doesn't work very well, it takes much longer than 10 seconds. Also, when I print to log System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime, it firstly show me for a while "0" then it changes... Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

libGDX has classes for what you want.

I suggest you use the [Time.Utils](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/TimeUtils.html) calss :

```
onCreate(){
    startTime = TimeUtils.millis();
}

render(){
    if(TimeUtils.millis() - startTime > 10000){
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem remains exactly the same. Even if I put > 1, it always waits as much as 10000, like that's the only moment it actually sees the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I somewhat finally figured out by myself. I need to use long to hold that size of values. It was kind of obvious.